# Why does sigmoid function outperform tanh and softmax in this case?

Tags: keras, neural-network

The sigmoid function gives better results than tanh or softmax for the below neural network.

If I change the activation function from sigmoid to tanh or softmax the error increases an accuracy decreases. Although I have learned that tanh and softmax are better compared to sigmoid. Could someone help me understand this?

The datasets I used are iris and Pima Indians Diabetes Database. I have used TensorFlow 1.5 and Keras 2.2.4

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

dataset = np.genfromtxt('diabetes.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
X = dataset[1:, 0:8]
Y = dataset[1:, 8]

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=50, batch_size=20)
print(model.metrics_names)
print(model.evaluate(xtest, ytest))
```

Comment: This makes no sense, softmax or tanh cannot be used with the binary cross entropy loss in that network, since it has only one output neuron. That explains why you get bad results.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Could u please elaborate ? I am not getting your point properly .

Comment: The binary cross-entropy loss assumes the targets are binary (0 or 1), and the predictions are in [0, 1] (continuous). If you use softmax with one neuron, the output will be a constant 1.0 that won't change, and if you use tanh, the output is in [-1, 1]

Answer (score 3):

The value range is between -1 and 1, but that's not necessarily a problem as far as the Tanh is concerned. By learning suitable weights, the Tanh can fit to the value range [0,1] using the bias. Therefore both the Sigmoid and the Tangh can be used here. Only Softmax is not possible for the reasons mentioned. See the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

X = np.hstack((np.linspace(0, 0.45, num=50), np.linspace(0.55, 1, num=50)))
Y = (X > 0.5).astype('float').T

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100)

print(model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=False))
```

Whenever someone says you should always prefer foo over bar in machine learning, it's probably an inadmissible simplification. There are anti-patterns that one can explain to people, things that never work, like the Softmax in the example above. If the rest were that simple, AutoML would be a very boring field of research ;) . PS: I'm not exactly working on AutoML.

Comment: +1 for "... foo over bar ...". How would "Tanh fit to the value range [0,1] using the bias" work? The regular "bias" wouldn't help help to fit to [0,1] because it cannot limit the output of tanh as weights / inputs change.

Comment: The neuron has weight w and a bias. Both together can be used fit to the ouput for all elements of the trainings set -- and hopefully the test set -- to [0,1]. Keep in mind it is all about the relevant subset of the vector space aka feature space. Not all of values of R^n. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Softmax activation function** is generally used as a categorical activation. This is because softmax squashes the outputs between the range (0,1) so that the **sum of the outputs is always 1**. If your output layer only has one unit/neuron, it will always have a constant 1 as an output.

**Tanh, or hyperbolic tangent** is a logistic function that maps the outputs to the range of (-1,1). Tanh can be used in binary classification between two classes. When using tanh, remember to label the data accordingly with [-1,1].

**Sigmoid function** is another logistic function like tanh. If the sigmoid function inputs are restricted to real and positive values, the output will be in the range of (0,1). This makes sigmoid a great function for predicting a probability for something.

So, all in all, the output activation function is usually not a choice of model performance but actually is dependent on the task and network architecture you are working with.